# How do I update the inner HTML of a div by changing a date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, date

I'm trying to make the content of my page dependent upon the date.

I'm using moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) to determine the date and some JS to change the date that is displayed at the top of the page. For the rest of the page's content, I'd like to have it dependent on the the date displayed at the top of the page.

I've been able to get the page's content to update to the current date, but not a future or past date as the user clicks the left and right arrows. I'm open to a different way to make the page's content dependent on the date, but this is what I have so far:

```
var displayDate = moment();

$('#date').text(displayDate.format('MMMM Do'));

$(".left-arrow").click(function(){
    $('#date').text(displayDate.add(-1, 'days').format('MMMM Do'));
});

$(".right-arrow").click(function(){
    $('#date').text(displayDate.add(1, 'days').format('MMMM Do'));
});

if ($('#date').text() == "April 8th"){
    $('#box1').text("Read chapters 1-3");
    $('#box2').text("Read chapters 1-3");
    $('#box3').text("Read chapters 1-3");  
};

if ($('#date').text() == "April 9th"){
    $('#box1').text("Read chapters 4-6");
    $('#box2').text("Read chapters 4-6");
    $('#box3').text("Read chapters 4-6");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on your left or right arrow you are setting the date correctly but the not running the if statements again to check what the new date is. You can wrap your if statements in a function and then call that function on the arrow press. For example:

```
function checkDate() {
    if ($('#date').text() == "April 8th"){
        $('#box1').text("Read chapters 1-3");
        $('#box2').text("Read chapters 1-3");
        $('#box3').text("Read chapters 1-3");  
    };

   if ($('#date').text() == "April 9th"){
       $('#box1').text("Read chapters 4-6");
       $('#box2').text("Read chapters 4-6");
       $('#box3').text("Read chapters 4-6");
    };
}
```

Then when you click the left or right arrow just run the checkDate function.

```
$(".left-arrow").click(function(){
    $('#date').text(displayDate.add(-1, 'days').format('MMMM Do'));
    checkDate();
});

$(".right-arrow").click(function(){
    $('#date').text(displayDate.add(1, 'days').format('MMMM Do'));
    checkDate();
});
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I needed. It works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you think it's the correct answer then marking as answer would be great! :)

Comment: I tried, but it says that because my rep is below 15, my vote is recorded but not shown publicly. :/  I guess the best I can do is come back when I'm ranked up enough and give you the credit. Sorry man

Comment: @codymillennial I didn't know about that. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and made a JSFiddle out of it. I also changed where you removed 1 day by using their "subtract" (which is in their examples). Like this:

```
$('#date').text(displayDate.subtract(1, 'days').format('MMMM Do'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0b6367k/